# In Pandas, is there a way to divide a cell by all other cells in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a matrix:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

Is there a way to divide every number by the sum of the other numbers in its column? The first number, 1, here at A, X would be 1/(3+6) = 0.1111.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
>>> df / (df.sum() - df)
          A         B         C
X  0.111111  0.181818  0.230769
Y  0.428571  0.444444  0.454545
Z  1.500000  1.166667  1.000000
```

which works because `df.sum()` gives us the column sums:

```
>>> df.sum()
A    10
B    13
C    16
dtype: int64
```

when we subtract `df`, the sum broadcasts, and so each element becomes the appropriate denominator:

```
>>> df.sum() - df
   A   B   C
X  9  11  13
Y  7   9  11
Z  4   6   8
```